# Cypher Maximum of Average

Tags: neo4j, cypher, aggregate

I've started learning of Cypher and I've met a problem with aggregation.
My DB has nodes MOVIE and relations RATED (it has a property "rating"). I want to take a node with maximum average rating [I mean max(avg(rating))]. Unfortunately, when I add "m" and "ar" in the second part, I'm receiving max value of each row but I need to calculate the overall maximum.

```
MATCH (m:MOVIE)-[r:RATED]-() WITH m, AVG(r.rating) AS ar
MATCH (m:MOVIE)-[r:RATED]-() m,ar,WITH max(ar) AS mr
WHERE ar = mr return m
```

P.S. It is clear that I can something like this

```
MATCH (m:MOVIE)-[r:RATED]-() WITH m, AVG(r.rating) AS ar RETURN m ORDER BY ar DESC LIMIT 1
```

but I just want to understand how to fix the previous query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the max of average ratings, you need to either eliminate or aggregate `m` and `ar`, so that that max() considers all rows (aggregations are calculated with respect to the non-aggregation variables, which form the grouping key).

Here's one way you could do it.

```
MATCH (m:MOVIE)-[r:RATED]-() 
WITH m, AVG(r.rating) AS ar
WITH collect({m:m, ar:ar}) as movies, max(ar) as max
UNWIND [movie in movies where movie.ar = max] as m
RETURN m
```